# C# WhenAll(tasks) crashes the app without any exception or error

Tags: c#, xamarin, smb

Quick Summary of the issue is that I am currently trying to create an application in Xamarin that finds the IP address of the connected PC (using SMB2). Using `await Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(Dns.GetHostName())` gets me the first three segment of the correct IP address. From here I ping all the address from 0 to 255 (for example xxx.xxx.xxx.0 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.255) and see if I get a response back.

The pinging creates a new Task for every IP address it tests (so 255) while pinging those address. Finally it will do `WhenAll(task)` and this is where the crash seems to be happening. The weird thing is that it doesn't crash every time but every 3-5 times that this method runs.

The pinging method:

```
        async Task PingAsyncCustom (List<String> testIPs)
        {
                if (Battery.PowerSource == BatteryPowerSource.Usb)
                {
                    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                    
                    foreach (string ips in testIPs) 
                    {
                        using (Ping ping = new Ping())
                        {
                            var taskPing = InitiatePing(ips, ping);
                            tasks.Add(taskPing);
                        }
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Crashes.TrackError(e);
                        Analytics.TrackEvent("WhenAll Crash" + e.ToString());
                    }
                    Report("Waiting Finished");
                    tasks.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
                    Report("Ping Async Finished");
                }
                else
                {
                    Report("Disconected during Ping Sweep");
                    pIps.Clear();
                }
            
        }
```

and the `initiatePing` method:

```
        private async Task InitiatePing (String ip, Ping ping)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PingReply>();
            var options = new PingOptions(64,true); 
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            try
            {
                Report("InitiatePing: " + ip);
                var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, 2000, buffer, options);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    lock (lockObj)
                    {
                        pIps.Add(reply);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(PingException e)
            {
                Report("PingException: " + e.ToString());
            }


        }
```

One more thing from output is that it seems to be creating way too many threads & sometimes, not always, it will show a fatal error: (snippet of one of my runs)

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #99
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #100
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #101
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #102
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #103
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #104
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #105
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #106
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #107
[libc] Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr
```

If there are better ways to implement this, I will gladly take your advice. If not, then maybe shining some light what the exact issue is and some solutions would be greatly appreciated.

"Previous Code changes:"
Originally it didn't have any try & catch in the `WhenAll(task)` so I added it, but it still seems to crash. Also tried removing the List once they reached completion. Also when creating new `Ping()`, I use `using` to properly dispose once done.

Comment: You are disposing each `Ping` instance twice, and one of those might be before the ping completed.

Comment: Crashing without exception? Can't believe. Did you attach WinDbg?

Comment: @StephenCleary disposing it twice? sorry where do you see that?

Comment: Once in the `using` and once in `InitiatePing` (if an exception is thrown).

Comment: Yeah, there is a significant chance that a Ping instance is being disposed of before the Ping instance got a chance to conclude all the network-y stuff necessary to do an actual ping... (Note that you don't await the task returned by InitiatePing before your code is disposing the Ping instances, which can lead to situations where the Ping object is being disposed of while InitiatePing is still doing its thing...)

Comment: I just removed it, but it seems like the crashing still persists. Crashed with the Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) error I posted in the question

Comment: Using `lock` inside a async method doesn't work as you expect. Consider using something that is async aware like SemaphoreSlim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a workaround, I was able to create a limit on the `list<task>` so it doesn't do `Task.WhenAll` on 254 addresses.

Code like below:

```
        async Task PingAsyncCustom (List<String> testIPs)
    {
            if (Battery.PowerSource == BatteryPowerSource.Usb)
            {
                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                
                foreach (string ips in testIPs) 
                {
                    if (Battery.PowerSource == BatteryPowerSource.Usb)
                    {
                        var taskPing = InitiatePing(ips);
                        tasks.Add(taskPing);
                        if (tasks.Count() == 10)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                            tasks.Clear();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Analytics.TrackEvent("Whenall10 Crash" + e.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pIps.Clear();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(e);
                Analytics.TrackEvent("WhenAll Crash" + e.ToString());
            }
                tasks.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                pIps.Clear();
            }
        
    }
```

For now the I use `tasks.count() == 10` but an improvement I can think of is to remove task that is completed and replace them with new task. Currently it will wait for all 10 to finish then jump onto the next batch of 10.